# Binding variable number of images in single WPF itemtemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a listbox and each item contains a title and a variable number of images, from 2 to 10+. Easy enough to do with a fixed number of images, but how can I set the itemtemplate to the varied number of images?

Comment: Post your current XAML and the class you're binding to (Data Item).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add ItemsControl into ItemTemplate

Something like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Something}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
           <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
       </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I did write this without knowing details of your object model, so this is more to give you idea...

Comment: Thanks, that did it (slight typo <ItemsControl.ItemsTemplate>)